# Programmatic use of Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, wicket

I am using [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) with the Wicket Auth Project for my presentation layer and I have therefore integrated it with Spring Security. This is the method which is called by Wicket for authentication for me:

```
@Override
public boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
    try {
        Authentication request = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username, password);
        Authentication result = authenticationManager.authenticate(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The contents (inside ) of my Spring Security XML configuration are:

```
<http path-type="regex">
    <form-login login-page="/signin"/>
<logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
<global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager"/>
<authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
    <password-encoder ref="bcryptpasswordencoder" />
</authentication-provider>
```

The section [2.3.6. Session Fixation Attack Protection](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-session-fixation) of the reference documentation says:

> Session fixation attacks are a potential risk where it is possible
>   for a malicious attacker to create a
>   session by accessing a site, then
>   persuade another user to log in with
>   the same session (by sending them a
>   link containing the session identifier
>   as a parameter, for example). Spring
>   Security protects against this
>   automatically by creating a new
>   session when a user logs in. If you
>   don't require this protection, or it
>   conflicts with some other requirement,
>   you can control the behaviour using
>   the session-fixation-protection
>   attribute on , which has three
>   options:
>
> - migrateSession - creates a new session and copies the existing
>     session attributes to the new session. This is the default.
> - none - Don't do anything. The original session will be retained.
> - newSession - Create a new "clean" session, without copying the
>     existing session data.

**The authentication works, but I as I'm fairly new to Spring Security I have some questions which I need answers too:**

- Normally for login, I would POST the authentication information to `j_spring_security_check` and let Spring Security perform the actual authentication code. I would like to have protection against session fixation attacks, will I get it when I perform a programmatic login as I do? And if not, what would I have to do to get it?
- How do I perform programmatic logout?
- As I will use programmatic login and logout, how do I disable Spring from intercepting those URL's?

**Update:**
For session fixation attack protection it seems that I need to call the method in the SessionUtils class with the signature `startNewSessionIfRequired(HttpServletRequest request, boolean migrateAttributes, SessionRegistry sessionRegistry)`.

How do I get the SessionRegistry instance which I need to pass in? I can't find any way to create an alias ID for it, or how to get it's ID or name.

Comment: Bounty is given to the first one posting an answer for the three questions above

Comment: Hey Kent - I answered the questions and you let the bounty expired - why?

Comment: Sorry, I had some personal matters which kept me from logging in.

Comment: See this question and answer for a better way to do programmatic logins. With this method, all the spring functionalities like session fixation protection will continue to work properly. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47233187/spring-security-manual-login-best-practice

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Maybe it's not a full answer to your questions, but maybe it might help you.

The code being called when you do NOT use programmatic login, but a standard one is to be found here:

`org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilter`

I guess you were inspired by this in your code. It looks quite similar.

Similarly the code executed when you access the `/j_spring_security_logout` in the standard approach, is to be found here:

`org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter`

The LogoutFilter calls multiple handlers. The handler we are using is called:
`org.springframework.security.ui.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler`, so you might call the same code in your approach.

Comment: What a nice answer! :-)

I was a bit more than inspired, by the Spring 3.0 reference documentation (the three lines in my try block are a straight copy-paste): http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/technical-overview.html#d4e689 .I should note though that I am using 2.0.4.

I'll look into the code you mentioned! Thank you! I'm leaving the question open for now, as I'm still looking for some answers to my OP questions.

Answer (score 8):

You will indeed be open to session fixations attacks. To remedy this you could again be "inspired" by the Spring code. To create a new session you'll obviously need access to the httpsession so you may have to do some refactoring.

If you see the method [`SessionUtils`](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~raw,r=3640/spring-security/trunk/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/session/SessionUtils.java).`startNewSessionIfRequired`.

This will migrate the authentication to a new session. You might be able to call this method directly or else just refactor the code a little.

As for programmatic logout you can't go too far wrong by simply calling `session.invalidate()` when you need to log the person out. This will do everything necessary from a general security perspective but bear in mind though you might need to cleanup some things on the session. If you have a very complicated set of filters etc. and you need to ensure that that the user is logged out for the rest of the request then you could add:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

As for interception of the url's you could just set them to something unused and ignore it! I'm not sure if you can turn off the interception in configuration - if you really want to remove it then have a look at the `AuthenticationProcessingFilter` - you could customise this. If you do this then you'll have to manually setup the spring security xml and not use the provided namespaces. It's not too hard though - look at some older documentation and you'll see how to do this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I created an update above as I'm having problems with the session fixation attack protection.

Comment: Have you a need to limit concurrent sessions? e.g. letting the same user login twice in two different sessions? If not you don't need a SessionRegistry - just pass a null value into the SessionUtils method.

If you do need this then when you implement it you'll have a sessionRegistry! 

see here:

http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-concurrent-session

Again for you you may need to configure it yourself and not use the custom namespace. 

My guess is you don't need this functionality.

Comment: SessionUtils was removed in spring-security 3.0, looks like org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy.onAuthentication() (and its subclass ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy) are its closest replacement.

Answer (score 6):

1) Programmatic Logout

1. call HttpServletRequest.getSession(false).invalidate
2. call SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()

2) Tell Spring Security NOT to intercept certain URLs, this one kind of depends on how your application url space is setup.  If all your pages (except /logIn and /logout) lived at the context /myApp then you could do this:

```
<http ....>
  <intercept-url pattern="/myApp/**" ..>
 ....
</http>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with programmatic login. I called all the `authenticationManager.authenticate(...)` and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(...)` methods but had some issues with the Session. I had to add the following lines to properly manage the session:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

This was not clear from the example code posted above. For more look at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=69761

Answer (score 0):

To do programmatic logout it's also possible to throw  an `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException`. For example, `SessionAuthenticationException`. In this case `ExceptionTranslationFilter` initiate logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }

        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(LogLevel.INFO, "Problem logging out.");
    }
```