# How to manually log out a user with spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security, logout

Probably the answer is simple: How can I manually logout the currently logged in user in spring security?
Is it sufficient to call:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().setAuthenticated(false);
```

?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers guys, I'll check them out.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Servlet 3.0 container Spring logout functionality is integrated with servlet and you just invoke `logout()` on your `HttpServletRequest`. Still need to write valid response content.

**According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.1.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#servletapi-logout)** (Spring 3.2):

> **The HttpServletRequest.logout() method can be used to log the current user out.**
>
> Typically this means that the SecurityContextHolder will be cleared
>   out, the HttpSession will be invalidated, any "Remember Me"
>   authentication will be cleaned up, etc.

Comment: Having an NPE at Tomcat 7's `org.apache.catalina.connector.Request#logout` implementation for Spring 3.1.2 / Grails 2.2.0. No such error with `clearContext()`.

Comment: @PavelVlasov I believe it's a some mistake in spring configuration, read about SecurityContextHolder.

Comment: After `request.logout()` I still has authorized user in 
`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`

Answer (score 81):

It's hard for me to say for sure if your code is enough. However standard Spring-security's implementation of logging out is different. If you took a look at `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` you would see they do:

```java
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Moreover they optionally invalidate the HttpSession:

```java
if (invalidateHttpSession) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        session.invalidate();
    }
}
```

You may find more information [in some other question about logging out in Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1013032/118587) and by looking at [the source code of `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/logout/SecurityContextLogoutHandler.html).

Comment: You'll also want to drop the rememberme cookie if that is set.

Answer (score 28):

I use the same code in LogoutFilter, reusing the LogoutHandlers as following:

```
public static void myLogoff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    CookieClearingLogoutHandler cookieClearingLogoutHandler = new CookieClearingLogoutHandler(AbstractRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY);
    SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    cookieClearingLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
    securityContextLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
}
```

Comment: +1 because of CookieClearingLogoutHandler otherwise user can log in again if she had the rememberme cookie. Note that this class requires spring 3.1

Comment: This is the correct working solution if you have custom RememberMe handling

Answer (score 10):

You can also use [SessionRegistry](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/session/SessionRegistry.html) as:

```
sessionRegistry.getSessionInformation(sessionId).expireNow();
```

If you want to force logout in all sessions of a user then use `getAllSessions` method and call `expireNow` of each session information.

**Edit**
This requires `ConcurrentSessionFilter` (or any other filter in the chain), that checks SessionInformation and calls all logout handlers and then do redirect.

Answer (score 10):

To log out a user in a web application you can also redirect him to the logout page. The LogoutFilter is then doing all the work for you.

The url of the logout page is set in the security configuration:

```
<sec:http ...>
  ...
  <sec:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout_successful=1" />
  ...
</sec:http>
```

Comment: This didnt work for me.  Its not as simple as you suggest.  Any more configuration details?

Comment: There should be no other configuration necessary for this to work. You simply redirect the user to an URL like "http://example.com/yourctx/logout".

Comment: I got it working but i had to restart Tomcat for it to start working.

Answer (score 4):

`new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, null, null);`

Answer (score 4):

Right Oledzki, I am using the following for example inside my controller to logout and redirect the user to the login page in spring security 4.2.3

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

if(session != null)
    session.invalidate();

return "redirect:/login";
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply do like this (the ones commented by "concern you") :

```
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); // concern you

    User currUser = userService.getUserById(auth.getName()); // some of DAO or Service...

    SecurityContextLogoutHandler ctxLogOut = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler(); // concern you

    if( currUser == null ){
        ctxLogOut.logout(request, response, auth); // concern you
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Recently we had to implement logout functionality using Spring-security 3.0.5. Although this question is already answered above, I will post the complete code which would definitely help novice user like me :)

Configuration in Spring-security.xml

```
 <http auto-config="false" lowercase-comparisons="false" use-expressions="true">
     <custom-filter position="LOGOUT_FILTER" ref="logoutFilter" />
 </http>

<beans:bean id="logoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="logoutSuccessHandler" ref="xxxLogoutSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:constructor-arg name="handlers">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="securityContextLogoutHandler"/>
            <beans:ref bean="xxxLogoutHandler"/>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logout"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="XXXLogoutSuccessHandler" class="com.tms.dis.sso.XXXLogoutSuccessHandler"/>
<beans:bean id="securityContextLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <beans:property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true"/>
</beans:bean>
<beans:bean id="XXXLogoutHandler" class="com.tms.dis.sso.XXXLogoutHandler"/>
```

Here i have created two custom classes

1. XXXLogoutHandler which will implement org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutHandler and will override the logout() method.
2. XXXLogoutSuccessHandler which will implement org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutSuccessHanlder and will override onLoguoutSuccess() method. Within the XXXLogoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess() method call the redirectStrategy.sendRedirect() method which logout the user to the particular targetURL.
3. org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler does the task of invalidating the user session.

Hope this would help and give the correct direction to the starter

**Note**: Intentionally have not posted code for custom implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, to logout of spring security manually,
just make use of the Servlet request itself.
i.e. As below :

```
@PostMapping("/manualLogout")
public String customLogut(Model models, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException
{
    request.logout();
    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Thanks for the question.

Answer (score 0):

In you *controller >> signOut method* **do not return "/logout"** but redirect to the /logout method in the spring security context: `return "redirect:/logout";`