# Spring security automatically logout with multiple roles

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have an app with multiple roles. First, I login with a role. Then in another tab, I try to login with another role, but intentionally the login failed because I put an incorrect password. Then, when I go to the other tab, where I am logued, if I click a menu option, then the application go to the login page, as if I had logged out.

This is my spring security configuration.

```
http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/j_spring_security_check*","/login*","/adminLogin*", "/superadminLogin*", "/logout*", "/signin/**", "/signup/**",
                        "/user/registration*", "/registrationConfirm*", "/expiredAccount*", "/registration*", 
                        "/badUser*", "/user/resendRegistrationToken*" ,"/forgetPassword*", "/adminForgetPassword*", "/resetPassword*","/user/resetPassword*", "/updatePassword*",
                        "/updatePassword*", "/user/updatePassword*", "/user/adminResetPassword*", "/registrationAdminConfirm*", 
                         "/emailError*", "/resources/**","/old/user/registration*","/successRegister*", "/user/setPassword*","/setPassword*", "/accountActivation*",
                         "/ayuda*", "/avisoLegal*", "/cookies*", "/activeAdminAccount*", "/user/changePassword*", "/changePassword*",
                         "/restablecerPasswordCode*", "/restablecerPassword*","/proteccionDatos*", 
                        "/comercializadoraLogin*", "/registrationComercializadora*", "/comercializadora/registration*",
                        "/comercializadora/resetPassword*", "/forgetPasswordComercializadora*", "/accountActivationComercializadora*",
                        "/comercializadora/changePassword*", "/restablecerPasswordComercializadora*",
                        "/comercializadora/getComercializadoras*", "/registrationRepConfirm*", "/backOfficeLogin*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/invalidSession*").anonymous()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
           .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/adminLogin.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/adminConsole.html")
                .failureUrl("/adminLogin.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(misConsumosAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/superadminLogin.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin.html")
                .failureUrl("/superadminLogin.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(misConsumosAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/backOfficeLogin.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/backOfficeConsole.html")
                .failureUrl("/backOfficeLogin.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(misConsumosAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/comercializadoraLogin.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/comercializadoraCansole.html")
                .failureUrl("/comercializadoraLogin.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(misConsumosAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
             .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html")
                .failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
                .failureHandler(misConsumosAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore((Filter) ajaxSessionFilter, SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .sessionManagement()
                //.invalidSessionUrl("/invalidSession.html")
                .invalidSessionUrl("/login.html")
                .sessionFixation()//.none()
                .changeSessionId()
            .and()
            .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(false)
                .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.html")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(misConsumosLogoutHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll();
```

Why does this happen? Is there a way to remain logged into the first tab?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: This is how HTTP sessions work. It uses the same HTTP session for different tabs / windows of the same browser. It has whatsoever nothing to do with Spring Security. Login with another authority / role using a different browser thus, a different client having a different HTTP session.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Investigating a little more, I have seen that the spring security calls to the logout function that delete the user data in the session. I found an answer that may be the solution to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/19567293