# Log out user by admin Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like your help to get how implement this function: 
admin gets all logged in users using sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals() and then can log off someone. 
I know how to log off current user (session.invalidate()), but have no idea how to force log out other users.

This code gets me all logged in users

```
public List<User> getAllLoggedInUsers() {
    List<Object> principals = sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
    List<User> usersNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Object principal : principals) {
        if (principal instanceof org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) {
            usersNamesList.add(dao.findByLogin(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) principal).getUsername()));
        }
    }
    return usersNamesList;
}
```

Thanks a lot.

EDIT 1: I want next: admin chooses a user, bans it (change info in DB) and then if this user is active - log him off.

Comment: I guess, the simplest solution would be to restart the application server. This will kill all the sessions.

Comment: @KrishnaKuntala I don't need it) I just want to figure out the way how to implement this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need a `sessionRegistry`, this can get all sessions and register new session:

```
@Bean
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
    return new SessionRegistryImpl();
}
```

Second, you need enable the `sessionRegistry` and use the `ConcurrentSessionFilter` to control the invalidate session.

```
http
 .sessionManagement() 
    .maximumSessions(-1)
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
```

the `-1` means no limit, **BUT this will register the `ConcurrentSessionFilter` and `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy` automatic. based the last spring security configuration**, If you use xml or old version of spring security, please find [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions) for help.

`ConcurrentSessionFilter` will get the session from `sessionRegistry`, and will do logout when the session is expired.

The last thing is inject the same `sessionRegistry` bean to your application when try to get session by user and expire the user's session.

> You can list a user’s sessions by calling the getAllSessions(Object principal, boolean includeExpiredSessions) method, which returns a list of SessionInformation objects. You can also expire a user’s session by calling expireNow() on a SessionInformation instance. When the user returns to the application, they will be prevented from proceeding.

Comment: Wow, that's was is more easier. 
I did not know sessionRegistry can provide all sessions. 
So I implemented that by myself.
I created class SessionCounterListener that implements HttpSessionListener and every time session is created I add it to the list.
So any time I can get the list of active sessions.

Answer (score -2):

suppose you try like this.

```
public void logoutUser(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
        Authentication auth = getAuthentication();

    for (int i = 0; i < logoutHandler.length; i++) {
        logoutHandler[i].logout(httpRequest, httpResponse, auth);
    }

        AnonymousAuthenticationToken aat = new AnonymousAuthenticationToken("your key you use",
                "anonymousUser", new GrantedAuthority[]{
                new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")});
        ((SecurityContext)SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).setAuthentication(aat);
    }
```

Also you can find more approaches in following [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727380/how-to-manually-log-out-a-user-with-spring-security) and [post2](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/35809-how-to-let-admin-to-force-user-to-logout).

you can also get the current logged users and set`SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null)`

Comment: Yea, that's the way to invalidate current active user session. But I need to invalidate not current but still active (logged in) user session.

Comment: @Paren'Vacya did mention that he knows how to log off the current user.