# How to logout user when update role with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am working on an application with several roles. Changing this role to admin user should log out the target user.

My first lead was to set up data tables to retrieve the list of active tokens by taking an example from this site:
https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-oauth2-jdbc-token-store-example/#3_Source_Code

Except that at the connection, the data information is not saved in my tables.

Is it possible to log out a user "by force"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727380/how-to-manually-log-out-a-user-with-spring-security) how you do it.
At the end of the day it invalidates the `Authentication` object in Spring's security context.