# How to get serialized tomcat HttpSession to repopulate spring SessionRegistry

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-security, httpsession

I do the following:

1. login to my spring application (e.g. as user 'admin')
2. stop tomcat
3. Now I see the session being serialized into **sessions.ser** file
4. I restart tomcat
5. the sessions.ser file disappears (I guess it is being deserialized during server start?)
6. Now I send a request which requires a logged-in user (as done
   in step 1, i.e. I hit F5 in the browser where I was already logged-in before, so I guess the request sends along the jSessionId etc.)
7. When debugging, I can observe how spring successfully loads the SecurityContext in

`HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession`

with the stored Session-Information (it is a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken containing an Authentication object containing the Principal etc. thus getting the custom User object seems possible)

8. Spring accepts the request, i.e. there is no need to re-login and the appropiate response is sent

However, when trying to list the logged-in users using the `SessionRegistry` via

```
for (Object principal : sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()) {
            MyCustomUser myCustomUser = (MyCustomUser) principal;
            ClientQueryDetails client = clientQuery.getDetails(myCustomUser 
                    .getClientId()).get();
            List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(
                    principal, false);
            for (SessionInformation sessionInformation : sessions) {
                result.add(new SessionInfo(client.getName(), myCustomUser 
                        .getUsername(), sessionInformation.getSessionId(),
                        sessionInformation.getLastRequest()));
            }
        }
```

as I normally do to visualize the users/sessions currently active, it is **empty**.

Why does Spring not add those Principals to the SessionRegistry in this moment?
Can/Should I do it somehow manually?

I've read https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2062 which sounds like doing so would be a bad idea.

Also related seems [Getting logged in users with sessionRegistry not work when manually authenticate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271727/getting-logged-in-users-with-sessionregistry-not-work-when-manually-authenticate)

I've also found http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/71503-spring-not-restoring-persistent-sessions-to-session-registry

So to summarize my questions:

1. Why doesn't spring re-add the serialized session informations to the `SessionRegistry`?
2. Is querying the `SessionRegistry` in order to display all active Sessions to the user (i.e. the logged-in users) the correct way to do so?
   **EDIT**
   Yes, this is definitely the purpose of the SessionRegisty: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#list-authenticated-principals
3. Should I add the `Principal`s manually to the SessionRegistry?
   **EDIT** 
   https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2062 provides different ways of manually readding sessions to the SessionRegistry, however it seems there are some caveats in doing so.
4. Where and how exactely is the Session from **sessions.ser** being deserialized into and where does spring obtain it? Or in other words, how does the session-information get from the sessions.ser file into the `SecurityContext` of spring? Especially how is it "handed over" from tomcat to spring?

Comment: #4: **sessions.ser** is Tomcat saving the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html), and has nothing to do with Spring. Spring can get information by calling [`getAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)). However, for the logged-in user, Spring can also call [`HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()). To see exactly what it does, look at the Spring source code.

Comment: The `SessionRegistry` is an in-memory map of currently attached users. That is obviously destroyed when you shutdown tomcat and empty when you start it. If you want that different use a persistent `SessionRegistry` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to the problem of not seeing Sessions in the SessionRegistry but having valid Sessions (i.e. logged-in users) is, to simply **delete the SESSIONS.ser File on Server restart**.

As a consequence, all users have to login again, and the SessionRegistry is populated accordingly. Since I have no pressing need to keep the sessions alive this is a good solution for me.