# spring security manual login best practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm using spring security to implement a programmatic, manual user login. I have a scenario where I have positively established the user's identity, and wish to log them in. I don't know their password, and so can't use the regular login code path where you submit a form to a url, which spring intercepts via a servlet `Filter`, doing all of it's auth+session magic.

I've searched, and it seems most people create their own `Authentication` object, and then tell spring about via:

```
PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authentication = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, "", user.getAuthorities());
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```

Indeed, this works. Spring even puts it into the session for me, making subsequent http requests maintain their auth status.

However, I feel like this is a dirty hack. I'll present some details that I hope will give concrete examples of the problems associated with using `setAuthentication()` inside a controller to achieve a manual login:

To give an idea, my config is:

```
httpSecurity
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/api/admin/**").hasRole("USER_SUPER_ADMIN")
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginPage("/sign-in?sp")
    .loginProcessingUrl("/api/auth/sign-in")
    .successHandler(createLoginSuccessHandler())
    .failureHandler(createLoginFailureHandler())
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/api/auth/sign-out")
    .logoutSuccessHandler(createLogoutSuccessHandler())
    .and()
    .sessionManagement()
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry)
;
```

Key points in the above config:

- I use custom success and failure handlers for the form login
- I want to config behavior for max concurrent sessions per user
- I want to maintain spring's default session fixation protection (changing session id upon login).
- I want to use a session registry
- ... more of these session/login functionalities, had I chosen to config it.

I stepped through the code to see how spring processes a form login. As expected, Spring does all the session/login functionalities that my `HttpSecurity` config told it to do when I use the form login. But, when I do my own custom/manual login via `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()`, it does NONE of those functionalities. This is because spring does all of it's session/login functionalities stuff inside of a servlet `Filter`, and my programmatic code can't really call a Filter. Now, I can attempt to add the missing functionalities myself, duplicating their code: I see that the spring Filter uses: `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`, `ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy`, and `RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy`. I can create these objects myself, configure them, and call them after my custom login. But, that's really lame to duplicate all that spring code. Furthermore, there's still other behaviors I'm missing - I noticed that when using the form login code path, that spring triggers some login events which don't get triggered when I do my custom login. And there's probably other stuff that I'm missing or don't understand. The whole process is pretty complicated, and I feel like there's a high chance of introducing bugs if this isn't done right, not to mention that library updates would be a pain if I started duplicating spring code.

So, I feel like I'm approaching this from the wrong way. **Should I be using a different strategy, so that I'm not bypassing so much of the stuff that spring does for me?** Maybe I should try to make my own `AuthenticationProvider` to accomplish this custom login?

*To clarify, my code more or less works. But, I feel like I accomplished it using a poor strategy because I had to write code duplicating a lot of stuff that spring does for me. Further, my code doesn't perfectly replicate what spring does, making me wonder what negative implications might result. There must be a better way to programatically achieve login.

Comment: It seems too broad. Can you reduce the content to provide relevant info regarding the problem and post [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce it.

Comment: @dur my custom(manual) login is used right after their initial account creation. I email them and have them click a link to verify their account. Upon clicking the link, I log them in without making them enter their credentials again. Since I don't have a password in this scenario, I can't use  any of the "normal" spring auth mechanisms, such as an `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider`. I also do basically the same thing if they forget their password, allowing them limited account access without necessarily having to change/reset their password, which is very important to my use case.

Comment: @dur, further, *even if I did have a password*, I don't really see a way to still get spring to do all of it's stuff for me, because spring does it's magic in a servlet `Filter`, well before my application code (eg in a controller) is executed. I need to make the call that establishes the login state, and all of its associated session stuff I listed, programatically.

Comment: @RomanC I don't think my question is broad at all. I'm asking for strategy advice from people who are extremely well versed with spring security. I presented details to give a concrete demonstration of the problems with the typical way that people do manual logins with spring. The details just give context - I don't think that makes the question broad. I don't see much value in providing a reproducible code sample here - my code works, I just don't like the strategy, and feel an expert may know a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For custom web authentication you should implement combination of a custom authentication filter (for example [`AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.html) or just [`GenericFilterBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html)), a custom authentication provider ([`AuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html)) or/and custom authentication token ([`AbstractAuthenticationToken`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationToken.html)).

For example, see source of [Spring Security Kerberos](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-kerberos).

See also:

- [The AuthenticationManager, ProviderManager and AuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/core-services.html#core-services-authentication-manager)

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to elaborate on how I implemented the advice of [dur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277820/dur). In my scenario, I only used a custom `AuthenticationProvider`.
Instead of creating a custom servlet `Filter`, such as extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`, which seemed like a lot of work, I choose to instead use the following strategy:

- At the point in my code where I was confident that I had identified the user, and wanted them to be "logged in", I stuck a flag in the user's session, marking that they should be logged in on the next request, along with any other identity/bookkeeping info I needed, such as their username.
- Then, I told the browser client to make an http post to the `loginProcessingUrl` (the same one I configured spring security to use for form-based login), telling them to send the standard `username` and `password` form params, although they don't need to send real values - dummy values like `foo` are fine.
- When the user makes that post request (eg to `/login`), spring will invoke my custom `AuthenticationProvider`, which will look in the user's session to check for the flag, and to gather the username. Then it will create and return an `Authentication` object, such as `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken`, which identifies the user.
- Spring will handle the rest. The user is now logged in.

By doing it this way, you stay within the "normal" way of doing logins, and so spring will still automatically:

- Call any custom success and failure handlers you configured for the form login, which is nice if you use that place to do certain things on login, like query or update a db.
- It will respect any max concurrent sessions per user settings that you may be using.
- You get to keep spring's default session fixation attack protection (changing session id upon login).
- If you set a custom session timeout, eg via `server.session.timeout` in a properties file, spring will use it. There's probably other session config attributes that are done at this time too.
- If you enabled spring's "remember me" functionality, it will work.
- It will fire a login event, which is used for other spring components, such as storing the user's session in a `SessionRegistry`. I think the events are also used by other parts of spring, such as the actuator, and for auditing.

When I first tried just doing the typically recommended `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication)` to login my user, instead of the custom `AuthenticationProvider`, none of the above bullets were done for me, which can utterly break your app... or cause subtle security bugs - neither are good.

Here's some code to help solidify what I said:

Custom AuthenticationProvider

```
@Component
public class AccountVerificationAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AppAuthenticatedUserService appAuthenticatedUserService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;
    
    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        // This will look in the user's session to get their username, and to make sure the flag is set to allow login without password on this request.
        UserAccount userAccount = authService.getUserAccountFromRecentAccountVerificationProcess();
        if (userAccount == null) {
            // Tell spring we can't process this AuthenticationProvider obj.
            // Spring will continue, and try another AuthenticationProvider, if it can.
            return null;
        }

        // A service to create a custom UserDetails object for this user.
        UserDetails appAuthenticatedUser = appAuthenticatedUserService.create(userAccount.getEmail(), "", true);

        PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(appAuthenticatedUser, "", appAuthenticatedUser.getAuthorities());
        authenticationToken.setAuthenticated(true);
    
        return authenticationToken;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

Config spring security to use the provider

```
// In your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppLoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private AccountVerificationAuthenticationProvider accountVerificationAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider;
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        // Spring will try these auth providers in the order we register them.
        // We do the accountVerificationAuthenticationProvider provider first, since it doesn't need to do any slow IO to check,
        // so it's very fast. Only if this AuthenticationProvider  rejects (which means this http request is not for programmatic login), will spring then try the next AuthenticationProvider in the list.
        authenticationManagerBuilder
            .authenticationProvider(accountVerificationAuthenticationProvider)
            // I'm using ActiveDirectory / LDAP for when a user logs in via entering a user + password via the html form, but whatever you want to use here should work.
            .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: To me, this doesn't sound like a general solution. What if there isn't one particular "place in the code" where the user is identified? For example, let's say we're sending out URLs through email with a one-time authentication token in the URL. That URL could end up anywhere... so there isn't one particular place where we can check their credentials.

Comment: And let's say we work around that problem by actually adding a filter... and somehow redirect the user's browser to the login form... that means the only place the user can end up is the home page, after they're redirected from the login form? If we want them to end up in any of many web pages, tough luck? I'm far from an expert on this stuff, I found your comments and idea intriguing, but I can't see how it can work as a general solution.

Comment: @xpusostomos General solution to what problem? I feel like you're describing features and requirements that are tangential to this Q&A. I can think of a few ways to implement the features you mentioned - Zillions of websites use this strategy: on page load, check is user logged in? no? then store current page in url or session, redirect to login page, after login redirect user back to stored page. you might even avoid redirects via crafty internal subrequests and/or servlet forwarding, possibly relaying the session id / cookies from the subrequest, or use a different strategy instead of mine.

Comment: what you're describing already exists in Spring. I was more thinking of authentication before you get to the page... like a one-time-use password recovery url login... which to be fair not many people may want to do like that. However I would say that implementing your own filter is a lot simpler than you make out. The only interesting extra step carried out in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter is a call to rememberMeServices... and if you inherit from that class (e.g. UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter), you don't even have to call that explicitely.

Comment: ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy is obsolete, and whatever ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy does, it does independently of any filter you write. So really the easier solution is shove something in the session, write  your own filter inheriting AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter, override attemptAuthentication to return success and you should be done.

Comment: When I did this ~4yrs ago I recall I looked into extending AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter but decided against it because I didn't feel that I could be confident I wouldnt cause a bug without first spending a lot of time studying that code and testing, both initially and when updating spring in the future. My experience is spring is complicated and not many users know it well enough to even realize their changes caused a bug, so I tread lightly and try to stick to well traveled paths when it comes to security related code. I bet it can work though, and would be more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example showing how to extend `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (or its parent `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`). This example disables the URL redirect functionality; but it could be customized in other ways or left in place. The remaining Spring features mentioned in the OP's answer are left untouched (handlers, sessions, events, remember-me, etc.) so their functionality isn't lost by simply manipulating the `SecurityContext` directly.

```
public class UserNamePasswordHeaderFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public UserNamePasswordHeaderFilter(RequestMatcher matcher, AuthenticationManager manager) {
        super(manager);
        setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(matcher);
        setPostOnly(false);
        setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        var successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy((request, response, url) -> {});  // No redirect.
        return successHandler;
    }

    @Override
    protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected String obtainPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getHeader(SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authResult);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);  // Continue the chain instead of redirecting.
    }
}
```

Note the `RequestMatcher` is not required if this Filter is to be applied on all paths, but it demonstrates how different filters could be applied selectively. The `username` and `password` can be retrieved from any part of the `request`. Using headers is just for demonstration. Extending `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` would allow creating a custom `Authentication` token, still without touching the `SecurityContext`.

In Spring 5.2+ consider instantiating [AuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationFilter.html) instead.